# Bringing element in front of an overlay without ruining existing styles

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Is there a way to bring a specific element over an overlay that covers the entire page of the browser? I need to do this without mucking up existing styles. I tried making a directive that applies position relative and z-index to a high number.This works,but if elements already have these properties, it would override them. It would be cool if I could just conditionally apply a class instead of replacing these attributes through the dom.

Comment: We need to see some code, otherwise we're just taking guesses. Give us a [mcve] of what you've got now along with what you've tried and what your end goal should look like.

Comment: Create a class with those properties and conditionally apply it so that it overrides the default values (use !important if you really have to).